# TableAdapter.Update() won't update

Tags: c#, database, datarow

I got some problems saving to my database. It updates my dataset and datagridview correctly but it doesn't update my database file and I don't get any errors. Can anyone help me out?

```
private void read_inv()
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Spacefrog\Desktop\dbfolder\1207.inv", Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string[] words = line.Split(' ');

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if (word != "" && (word.Length >= 3 ))
            {
                DateTime currentdate = DateTime.Now;
                string datumkort = currentdate.ToString("MMdd");

                DataRow[] findRow = mainDataSet.Tables["AFGEWERKT"].Select("PART = 'GBL14038F_SPO2_VF' AND DATUMKORT = '1211' ");
                int partsdone = Convert.ToInt32(findRow[0]["PARTSDONE"]);

                findRow[0].SetField("partsdone", partsdone + 1);
                findRow[0].AcceptChanges();

                aFGEWERKTTableAdapter.Update(findRow[0]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't use acceptchanges(), I got an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Parameter ?_16 has not defaultvalue.

Comment: `AcceptChanges()` doesnt do what it looks like you think it does.  You are setting the RowState to Unchanged so that there is nothing to update